# Содержимое файлов.css не выгружаются через @import url()

Tags: css, css3, github, импорт

Задача: Выложить проект на github  [https://github.com/MaankaYa/MaankaYa.github.io/tree/master/Проект%2003/Проект%2003](https://github.com/MaankaYa/MaankaYa.github.io/tree/master/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%2003/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%2003).

Проблема: Не выгружаются стили, в которых есть ссылки к другим стилям.

Стили без ссылок выгружает корректно.

Ошибки:
root__section.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
user-info__photo.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
Аналогичных ошибок еще 36.

Что есть: основной index.css к нему подключен другой файл popup.css через @import url("../blocks/popup/popup.css"), а к popup.css подключены еще 7 стилей через @import url(), например, @import url("./__content/popup__content.css"); Вот эти стили не выгружаются.

Пути решения: Проверка корректного отображения всех стилей через локальный сервер vscode. Проверка синтаксиса написания путей. Поиск ответа в инете.

Есть предположение, что если упростить и убрать ссылки, то вероятно заработает и верстка встанет на место. Но прежде, чем начать ломать, хочу понять, почему не выгружает остальные файлы css с ссылками.

[image: основной index.css к нему подключены другие файлы css]

[image: К другим файлам css подключены еще файлы css]

Comment: css импорты работают на клиенте и путь должен быть относительно размещения на хосте

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev Благодарю за обратную связь. Если есть возможность, прошу расскажите подробнее, желательно с примерами. Перебирала варианты путей, пока безуспешно. Может ли быть, что github не поддерживает импорт стилей, так как другие проекты, в которых нет импорта в файлах корректно выгрузились.

Comment: нет, проблем с хостом быть не должно, тк повторюсь - они работают на клиенте. путь желательно указывать от рута домена - `/blocks/root/root.css` и этот стиль должен быть доступен по `https://mysite.com/blocks/root/root.css`